# How to join the elevation of two surfaces with different shapes in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make 2 surfaces in compose look like a single one but when I add elevation to the surfaces it becomes obvious they are 2 separate ones.

[image: Picture of the 2 surfaces]

But I can't just join the 2 shapes into a complex one because I need them to scale independently (the top horizontally and the bottom one vertically).

Is there any way to add elevation to both surfaces as one without actually joining them into one surface.

Comment: Not really. Android doesn't actually do any kind of 3D tracing or rendering for shadows. Basically, for each elevated surface it draws a shaped blob that is skewed and shifted to adjust for elevation and screen position, to mimic real shadows cheaply. I'm thinking the best you could do with two separate surfaces is to clip the shadow on the top one, but it won't look quite right and might be pretty tedious. It's probably just as easy to do it with one surface, and reset the shape when needed.

Comment: No matter which order you draw these 2 composbles there will be shadow in intersection of Surfaces. You need to create shape using onTextLayout callback of Text to get size of shape on top, then creat that shape and add it to Path and easiest part is adding rounded rectangle to Path. When you have this shape you will have a proper elevation/shadow